# Install Referrer Library v1.1 adds permissions

Tags: android, install-referrer

Updating the Install Referrer Library from v1.0 to v1.1 added the following permissions:

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>
> READ_PHONE_STATE

Those permissions are not present in the Install Referrer Library manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.installreferrer" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

Source:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.installreferrer/installreferrer/1.1

Why those permissions added to the merged manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.1 and 1.1.1 are missing "minSdkVersion". This would automatically add those permissions. See similar issue here: [Google Play Services 12.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_version_1201).

**Solution**

Version 1.1.2 solves this issue.

**Details**

Manifest.xml for v1.0 (from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.installreferrer/installreferrer/1.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.android.installreferrer" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

Manifest.xml for v1.1 (from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.installreferrer/installreferrer/1.1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.android.installreferrer">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because they have added a dependency to

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.2.1
```

Which adds those permissions.

You can find it on the file:
manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt
which is under "yourApp/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/debug

It's probably a bug. I currently just downgraded back to 1.0. 
But if you need this version you can add

```
<uses-permission android:name="<permission_name>" tools:node="remove" />
```

To disable it. 

**Know that if you'll use any API which needs it inside the library it could lead to a crash so i won't recommend doing so.**

Comment: Thanks. I've also downgraded to 1.0.